# zendesk zcli gives error Error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Tags: zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I have followed all instruction given here
https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/developer-tools/getting-started/setting-up-your-development-environment/

and
https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/app-developer-guide/zcli/

I am running Ununtu22.04 LTS on windows 10 wsl.
when i give a command

> zcli login -i

Subdomain: xyz

Email: user@mydomain.com

Password: ***

**Gives below error**

Error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this post](https://anto.online/guides/cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20solution,need%20to%20install%20two%20applications.) help you ?

> By default, Docker looks for the native binary on each of the platforms; i.e., “osxkeychain” on macOS, “wincred” on windows, and “pass” on Linux. A special case is that on Linux, Docker will fall back to the “secretservice” binary if it cannot find the “pass” binary.

> The simplest solution to fix the “Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY” error is to install pass—the standard UNIX password manager. You do not need to remove docker-compose! However, the pass depends on gpg, so you will need to install two applications.

Cheers